# Name of a board game with a world map and an airplane traveling to different cities

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to find the name of an old board game.

It had a picture of the world on the board with different cities. A line is drawn from each city to a destination. That is the only place that city can fly too.

The pieces are an airplane and cards that has pictures of each city on them that can be flown too. The plane can only go to where the line is drawn to another city. Example: if the plane is in Rome, the plane may only go to London, Paris, or Rio de Janeiro.

Also there are fake 100 dollar bills. Each player bids on the flight. Whoever wins the bid sends the plane to one of those 3 cities then from there bidding starts again to go somewhere else.

The idea is to go to all the cities you have in your hand. I believe the name of the game is **Holiday** or something like that.

If anyone knows the name of the game, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give us any other information about the game? For example, how many players is it for, roughly how long does it take, and even what year you did you first play it (as a upper bound for the publishing year).

Answer (score 4):

Your memory of the game's name is pretty much correct,
The game in question is called "[**Holiday!**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/512/holiday)"
(*note the **!**, as there is another game called* "Holiday" *that is quite different to what you remember*).

The rules to "**Holiday!**" are almost exactly as you remember, with the addition that the destination cards also hold a day of the week, which awards a player additional points for reaching the destination on that day.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some information (other than the link, which might not work forever) why you think this is the correct game?

Comment: @ZeissIkon additional details added, but the question answers itself, this is just validation that the asker's memory is correct.